# Is the attack roll how much damage I do?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack-roll

When I roll the die on my turn to attack and roll 15 does that mean I do 15 damage? It confuses me because I see most people's characters only have around 10 hit points which would mean majority of the time they will just die.

Comment: Yes I have the rule book from the mines of phandelver core set starter set

Comment: related: [How exactly does the Attack Bonus on Weapons work in DnD 5e?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48435/23064), [How do I understand the Starter Set attack roll?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91322/23064) possible duplicate: [I'm confused about combat; how can I hope to hit anything?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47360/23064)

Comment: How much of the free Basic Rules have your read about making attack rolls? Is there something there that still confuses you?

Comment: Yeah just the attacking, like rolling a 15, does that mean it does 15 damage

Answer (score 4):

**No**, rolling a 15 is not 15 damage.

An attack and its damage in D&D is (since at least 3rd edition!) handled in two steps:

1. Roll 1d20 + Attack Bonus (depends on your edition, class and stats) + situation modifiers (including penalties)

   - If you roll the targets Armor Class (AC) or higher, goto 2, otherwise goto 3
2. Check your weapon's damage: roll that die, possibly add stat modifiers.
3. That was your action. Check if you got another, otherwise you are finished.

Comment: I think this would be improved with some pointers to the relevant rules: OP indicates they're using the Starter Set, and all of this is covered in that book's second chapter, which runs all of 4 pp. if I'm recalling correctly. (AFB 'til tomorrow.)